# Adding different types charts in one place of Plotly make_subplots grid

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

I want to make board with some KPI cards. Each card is a combined graph assembled from area chart and indicator. When I try to add a visualization to the grid, I get an error: `Trace type 'indicator' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy' at grid position (1, 1)`

My code:

```
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1
    ,cols=3
    ,specs=[[{"type": 'indicator', 'type' : 'xy'}, {"type": "indicator"}, {"type": "indicator"}]]
    )

fig_add = fig.add_trace(
            go.Indicator(
                mode="number+delta"
                ,value=crime_stat.loc[crime_stat['year'] == 2016, 'assault_cnt'].max()
                ,number_font={
                    'size' : 36
                    ,'color' : '#71797E'
                    }
                ,delta={
                    'reference' : crime_stat.loc[crime_stat['year'] == 2015, 'assault_cnt'].max()
                    ,'relative' : True
                    ,'valueformat' : '.1%'
                    ,'font_size' : 24
                    })
            ,col=1
            ,row=1)

fig_add = fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                x=crime_stat['year']
                ,y=crime_stat['assault_cnt']
                ,fill='tozeroy'
                ,marker_color='#C6C5C5')
            ,col=1
            ,row=1)

fig_add.show()
```

I tried to specify `specs=[[{"type": 'indicator'}, {"type": "indicator"}, {"type": "indicator"}]]`. Then I got an error: `Trace type 'scatter' is not compatible with subplot type 'domain'`.
If I tried to specify `specs=[[{"type": 'xy'}, {"type": "indicator"}, {"type": "indicator"}]]`, I got an error: `Trace type 'indicator' is not compatible with subplot type 'xy'`.

How can I fixed that?

Example of a visualization I want to add:

[image: KPI card]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to guess that since the indicator is positioning in an area, it may not be necessary to specify a trace type. The graph was created successfully. I customized the reference example and used sample data taken from plotly. Domain values are set manually in the range of 0 to 1. Also the spacing of `'x':[0.65,0.9]` affects the size of the letters.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.stocks()
#fig = go.Figure()
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2,
                    specs=[[{"type": 'scatter'}, {"type": "scatter"}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    y = df.AAPL.tolist(), fill='tozeroy', line_color='red', opacity=0.3, showlegend=False), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    y = df.GOOG.tolist(), fill='tozeroy',line_color='green', opacity=0.3, showlegend=False), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 492,
    delta = {"reference": 512, "valueformat": ".0f"},
    title = {"text": "APPL"},
    domain = {'y': [0, 1], 'x': [0.1, 0.35]}))

fig.add_trace(go.Indicator(
    mode = "number+delta",
    value = 550,
    delta = {"reference": 505, "valueformat": ".0f"},
    title = {"text": "GOOG"},
    domain = {'y': [0, 1], 'x': [0.65, 0.9]}))


fig.update_layout(xaxis={'range': [0, 62]}, template='plotly_white')

fig.update_layout(xaxis={'visible':False,'showgrid':False, 'showticklabels':False},
                  yaxis={'visible':False,'showgrid':False, 'showticklabels':False})

fig.update_layout(xaxis2={'visible':False,'showgrid':False, 'showticklabels':False},
                  yaxis2={'visible':False,'showgrid':False, 'showticklabels':False})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a very useful way for my case. I also found a solution to this problem, but I did it by combining the rows and columns of the grid.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem as follows:

```
# Create the first indicator
# The name of the variable can be deciphered as column 1 row 1
c1r1 = go.Indicator(
            mode="number+delta"
            ,value=crime_stat.loc[crime_stat['year'] == 2016, 'assault_cnt'].max()
            ,number_font={
                'size' : 36
                ,'color' : '#71797E'
                }
            ,title_text = 'All assaults (2016 vs 2015)'
            ,title_font={
                'size' : 18
                ,'color': '#585E62'
                }
            ,delta={
                'reference' : crime_stat.loc[crime_stat['year'] == 2015, 'assault_cnt'].max()
                ,'decreasing_color' : '#CB5E48'
                ,'increasing_color' : '#4A8F45'
                ,'relative' : True
                ,'valueformat' : '.1%'
                ,'font_size' : 24
                })

# Creating a background graph for the first card
c1r2 = go.Scatter(
            x=crime_stat['year']
            ,y=crime_stat['assault_cnt']
            ,fill='tozeroy'
            ,marker_color='#C6C5C5'
            ,marker_size=1)

# Creating the second indicator
c2r1 = go.Indicator(
            mode="number+delta"
            ,value=crime_stat.loc[crime_stat['year'] == 2016, 'firearm_ratio'].max()
            ,number_font={
                'size' : 36
                ,'color' : '#71797E'
                }
            ,number_suffix='%'
            ,title_text='<br><br>Firearm ratio (2016 vs 2015)'
            ,title_font={
                'size' : 18
                ,'color': '#ADADAD'
                }
            ,delta={
                'reference' : crime_stat.loc[crime_stat['year'] == 2015, 'firearm_ratio'].max()
                ,'decreasing_color' : '#CB5E48'
                ,'increasing_color' : '#4A8F45'
                ,'position' : 'right'
                ,'suffix' : '%'
                ,'valueformat' : '.1'
                ,'font_size' : 20
                })

# Creating a background graph for the second card
c2r2 = go.Scatter(
            x=crime_stat['year']
            ,y=crime_stat['firearm_ratio']
            ,marker_color='#B9D8E8'
            ,marker_size=1
            ,line_width=4)

# On the third card we will have two indicators at once
c3r1 = go.Indicator(
            mode="number"
            #,domain={'y' : [0.5, 1]}
            ,value=crime_stat['assault_cnt'].sum()
            ,title_text="No firearm<br>total assaults:"
            ,title_font={
                'size' : 18
                ,'color': '#71797E'
                }
            ,number_font={
                'size' : 32
                ,'color' : '#457291'
                })

c4r1 = go.Indicator(
            mode="number"
            #,domain={'y' : [0.5, 1]}
            ,value=crime_stat['assault_cnt'].mean()
            ,title_text = 'Mean<br>per year:'
            ,title_font={
                'size' : 18
                ,'color': '#71797E'
                }
            ,number_font={
                'size' : 32
                ,'color' : '#457291'
                })

# Creating a background graph for the third card
c3r2 = go.Histogram(
            x=crime_stat['year']
            ,y=crime_stat['no_firearm']
            ,histfunc='sum'
            ,marker_color='#C6C5C5'
            ,xbins_size=1
            ,opacity=0.6)

# Creating a grid
fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2
    ,cols=4
    ,column_widths=[0.35, 0.35, 0.15, 0.15]
    ,specs=[
            [{"type": "indicator", "rowspan": 2}
                ,{"type": "indicator", "rowspan": 2}
                ,{"type": "indicator", "rowspan": 2}
                ,{"type": "indicator", "rowspan": 2}
            ]
            ,[{"type": "xy", "rowspan": -2}
                ,{"type": "xy", "rowspan": -2}
                ,{"type": "xy", "rowspan": -2, 'colspan' : 2}
                ,None
            ]
        ]
    )

# Adding ready-made shapes to the grid
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c1r1, col=1, row=1)
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c1r2, col=1, row=2)
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c2r1, col=2, row=1)
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c2r2, col=2, row=2)
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c3r1, col=3, row=1)
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c4r1, col=4, row=1)
fig_add = fig.add_trace(c3r2, col=3, row=2)

fig_add = fig.update_layout(
            plot_bgcolor='#ffffff'
            ,width=1200
            ,height=330
            ,showlegend=False
            ,bargap=0.15
            ,margin_pad=5)

fig_add = fig.update_xaxes(
            showline=True
            ,linewidth=1
            ,linecolor='#C6C5C5'
            ,mirror=True
            ,showticklabels=False)

fig_add = fig.update_yaxes(
            showline=True
            ,linewidth=1
            ,linecolor='#C6C5C5'
            ,mirror=True
            ,showticklabels=False)

fig_add.show()
```

I got this result:
[image]

Comment: It's a hack I didn't know about either. I would recommend posting the full code for users with similar needs, as it is difficult to understand with just the subplot configuration information.

Comment: Added the full code